# Strange Fotorama behavior in Samsung Android default browser

Tags: android, browser, samsung-mobile, fotorama

I created a page using [Fotorama 4](http://www.fotorama.io). The code is as below:

```
<div class="fotorama" data-fit="contain" data-height="97%" data-width="100%" data-ratio="600/923">
  <img src="images/img1.png" data-caption="Caption 1">
  <img src="images/img2.png" data-caption="Caption 2">
  <img src="images/img3.png" data-caption="Caption 3">
  <img src="images/img4.png" data-caption="Caption 3">
</div>
```

The image slideshow is shown correctly in most browsers, except for Samsung's Android **default browsers** (Mobile Google Chrome works fine). We cross-checked with the following devices:

Display Error 1:

- Samsung Galaxy Note 1 ( Android OS 4.0.4 )
- Samsung Galaxy Note 2 ( Android OS 4.1.2 )
- Samsung Galaxy S2 ( Android OS 4.0.4 )

Display Error 2:

- Apple iPad 2 ( iOS 4.3.5 )

Display Okay:

- LG Optimus 3D ( Android OS 2.2 )
- Apple iPhone 4 ( iOS 6.1.3 )
- Apple iPhone 5 ( iOS 6.1.4 )
- Sony Xperia Z Tablet ( Android OS 4.1 )
- Samsung Galaxy S3 ( info given by @DeveloperCoder )

For Display Error 1, the 3rd & 4th image cannot be shown (probably due to load-on-demand does not trigger when swipe).

For Display Error 2, the animation is laggy. (this question focuses on Display Error 1)

Is there any workaround ?

Here is the [cross-link](https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues/41) of bug report in GitHub.

**Hint given by Fotorama 4 author:** Adding `#quirks` at the back of URL temporarily solved the problem.

Comment: Сan you give us a little demo?

Comment: Here is a test link : http://dev.raptor.hk/fotorama4/ . Please view it in Samsung default browsers ( just tested on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 ).

Comment: no problem on galaxy s 3